# Create app with Qt and OpenCV in Visual Studio 2013 Linking problems

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project that consists of a couple modules (5 in total). I need a standalone version of these so they can be tested (they are processing steps). I also need a version that combines them all to one programm. For the standalone testing all of them have some extra main-file and IO to read input/write output from/for the other modules (the complete app mostly doesn't need those). Standalone all modules are running just fine.

The problem now is that module 2-5 require OpenCV for the processing stuff and module 1 requires Qt for visuals.
I try to include 2-5 into 1 (so 1 also needs opencv), so I've put them into the project folder for that project, structure looks like this:

```
M1
    - QtTest        // this is actually M1, I didn't manage to rename that yet
        - Debug
        - GeneratedFiles
        - M2        // M2-5 contain the .h and .cpp of the respective M
        - M3
        - M4
        - M5        // this one also has a portable blender, a folder with a model and a folder with python scripts
        - OpenCV
            - build
                - include
                    - opencv2           // with all the files of opencv
                - x64
                    - vc12              // for now, only one of those when working correctly
                        - bin           // dll
                        - lib           // compact .lib
                        - staticlib     // single .libs'
        - Output
        - Resources
        - x64
        - [All the .h, .cpp, .props. etc. for M1]
    - Win32 
    - x64
    - QtTest.sdf
    - QtTest.sln
```

Now, I am using `Visual Studio 2013` with `Qt5.4` and `Opencv3`. I want to include OpenCV into the application
though without the user having to install Opencv (and no need for an environment variable) for size and convenience reasons, I need to include blender too (as portable folder only though).
(This is study project.)

I have additional dependencies for M2-5 and OpenCV like these (two new x64 props sheets, one for OpenCV and and for all the modules):
C/C++ > General > Additional includes:

- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\M2
- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\M3
- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\M4
- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\M5
- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\OpenCV\build\include

Linker > General > Additional libs:

- $(SolutionDir)QtTest\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12\   with either   bin, lib
  or staticlib

Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies (depending on bin, lib or staticlib):

- opencv_world300d.dll

  or
- opencv_world300d.lib

  or
- all .lib files from staticlib

For both sheets I've switched `Codegeneration` between `MTd` (lib and staticlib) and `MDd` (bin). The project itself too in relation.

I am getting a good amount of Linker errors now being

- LNK2038: RunrimeLibrary -> MDd_DynamicDebug and MTd_StaticDebug          //
  That has to do with some stuff (libs) being dll and some lib
- LNK2005: Already defined, entries in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) and
  msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll) conflicting with
  LIBCMTD.lib(typeinfo.obj) and
  libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj/xtrow.obj/syserror.obj)
- LNK4098 (warning): msvcrtd.lib conflicts with others, should use
  /NODEFAULTLIB
- LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol (24 errors), all to functions
  from modules 2-5

How can I set this up? Preferably I would like to just have `bin` or `lib` since `staticlib` is pretty big too.

(I can give more information if needed.)

Comment: Wow, what a mess. What exactly do you mean by "I want to include OpenCV into the application"? What's the reason for such a convoluted directory structure? Third party binaries deep inside your code, nested code directories, the compilation output mixed inside that, etc. You also seem to be mixing debug and release libs in one build, causing all those runtime conflicts. Look at how openCV is organized for some inspiration. At this size of project, I'd recommend using CMake to generate the solution.

Comment: Well, the application shall take an image, do some analizing and then modify a 3d model based on that. There are a couple steps in this and they need to be testable so they are made as seperate modules (5). Modules 2+3 (mainly) use OpenCV to do the analizing and module 1 is a GUI made with Qt. Obviously it's not convenient for a user to run these modules one by one so they shall combined in a single. The first one seemed to be the best choice for including the other ones.

Comment: For OpenCV I actually use the debug libraries also for release builds (even though it's currently only debug ones) because there were some problems with the release versions (can't quite remember, but they were like a-level so it was recommended to use the debug version to avoid that problem).

Comment: I don't mean the way you want to modularize it, that makes sense. I mean the organization of the source tree. -- I assume M2..M5 are libraries that you then link to M1? Or did you just add all the .c and .h files from those modules into M1 directly? -- Right now, there's not really enough info here to be able to tell what exactly you're doing wrong there. We'd need to see the whole solution and project settings, especially what libs you're linking in where.

Comment: Ah, yes, those folders just contain the .h and .cpp like I commented in the folder structure. That's basically just for organization. M2-5 or no labraries.

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing dynamically and statically linked runtime libraries. You should use the dynamic runtime -- so `/MDd` for Debug and `/MD` for Runtime. That should solve the first 3 link errors. Don't use the Debug DLL in Release build -- if nothing else, it's unoptimized and will be slow. ; Regarding directory organization, I personally do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/z0yi9Nhi). Put reusable code into libraries, make small application projects that use them.

Comment: Well, all the code for the modules can't (or better shouldn't) be in libraries for this because e.g. module 5 needs to run some external stuff (blender with a python script) and has to write data to a file for that (which is read by the python script). For dll/lib I tried all three possible ways (using one of the three folders from opencv, bin, lib and staticlib). This solution (I have to look up which one it now actually was) produced the least errors. Another one produced a lot more linking errors, mostly with the M2-5 stuff. That might be because those where compiled with dll I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made some mistakes there.
There was no need to put includes for the module folders. Adjusted everything to dll (MDd/MD, vc12/lib, opencv_ts300(d).dll + opencv_world300(d).dll), so the linking errors and so on are fixed.

There was on error following on that, a no entry point error for `matchTemplate(...)`. I switched to a newer version of opencv (had one of the early versions, alpha or beta). 3.1 is working, might actually go to 3.0 stable release.